# Output: mount: unknown filesystem type 'glusterfs'

Tags: kubernetes

> FailedMount   MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume
>   "kubernetes.io/glusterfs/f8c3bcce-42010a80007d-glusterfsmilogvol"
>   (spec.Name: "glusterfsmilogvol") pod "f8c3bcce-42010a80007d" (UID:
>   "f8c3bcce--42010a80007d") with: glusterfs: mount failed: mount failed:
>   exit status 32 Mounting arguments: IPAddress:GlusterTestVol
>   /var/lib/kubelet/pods/f8c3bcce-42010a80007d/volumes/kubernetes.io~glusterfs/glusterfstestlogvol
>
> glusterfs [log-level=ERROR
>   log-file=/var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/glusterfs/glusterfstestlogvol/pod-22ohg-glusterfs.log]
>   Output: mount: unknown filesystem type 'glusterfs'

Answer (score 1):

Further Analysis revealed that I am on Kubernetes 1.4, which has gci as image-type for the node.
https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/node-image-migration
Since Kubernetes 1.4, gci image is defaulted for GKE Container Cluster and it is not supporting GlusterFS FileSystem as PV - Persistent Volume.

So, converted image-type from gci to container_vm

***gcloud container clusters upgrade --image-type=container_vm "test-cluster"***

Also, further note says that
The following Kubernetes volume types that were supported in deprecated **container-vm**, are not yet supported in **gci**:

NFS

GlusterFS

iSCSI

Comment: Support for those file systems on GCI is being added and should be available in the near future. Please see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/34127 for details.

Comment: Thanks Anirudh. I subscribed to that issue 34127